# <a href ></a> does not redirect on single click

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have the following code in a script:

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/reelreview">Home</a>
```

When I left-click the link (single click), it doesn't redirect. It will redirect when I go to the target by right clicking and selecting "open in new window."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see the source for your page? It sounds like there may be something amiss elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Sunil Kumar P: If you have a live URL to share then we can help you easily. Or you can share your whole code at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/reelreview">Home</a>';
?>
```

above code is working very fine for me. It takes me to login page for apps. 
Do check ur mouse setting. hope this helps you.

regards

Comment: Please click in the home link of http://apps.facebook.com/reelreview/reviewMovie.php?m=2ad39e4f50cdd1330a5ac06f6. Is it working well ? Are you sure ? I have tried a lot and no result .Please chek it carefully because your answer  downs by reputation :(